# Transistor replacement on DP35DP motherboard

Tags: transistors, mosfet, identification, repair, motherboard

I have an old Intel DP35DP motherboard. I was using this board as a file server using RAID (it is crucial to get that RAID array working again).

It seems like the culprit is a transistor, its resistance is now almost 0, not enough to beep, but well below the others in circuit of the same model and the SMD capacitors around it are all in short.

The transistor/MOSFET reads 823 T23 N03G but I can't find its datasheet anywhere, therefore I do not know how to pick a replacement.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a power mosfet, I found it here https://ro.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ON-Semiconductor/NTD23N03RG?qs=ZXBb0xZ9WeA5xo9SNYh98g%3D%3D

The replacement it's not very easy if you dont have the necessary tools. You need a soldering station with hot air gun.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness, anyway that one says obsolete and not available anymore. So Im looking for a replacement. P.D. I have the required tools to do the job.

Comment: Look for the replacement on old motherboards, that people throw into trash. Just make sure that DS voltage, D current and G capacitance are ok

Comment: Your photo is fuzzy but the lower of the two black axial capacitors appears to be failing. The top looks swollen. You might want to check them. I would them to fail before any semiconductor device.